# Buffer Overflow Test on Fedora 32-bit not changing $eip register value

Tags: c, gdb, fedora, cpu-registers, buffer-overflow

I am trying to perform a simple buffer overflow on 32-bit Fedora, but the eip register value is not changing

My C code is as follows :

```
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    char buffer[8];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
}
```

I have tried executing :

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

to disable any kind of protection.
As well as I have compiled like this:

```
gcc -g -Wall -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 boftest.c -o boftest
```

When I run the command

```
./boftest AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD
```

And then observe the register values using gdb;
I see that:

```
ebp contains  0x44444444, but 
eip contains 0x80483F4
```

which means $eip hasn't been  successfully modified.

I have read other questions with the same problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.
Would you have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: You do realize that you invoke UB when you pass `AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD`, right?

Comment: Use `strndup` instead. I think you're trying to pass `AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD` as an address, so you need to use a function similar to `atoi`.

Comment: The behavior of the array overflow is undefined, what do you expect exactly ?

Comment: You should try using longer argument. Also show the disassembly of `main` and the exact place where you are looking at `$EIP` (better show the entire GDB session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured out what was going wrong eventually. I was trying the buffer overflow test on Linux's Fedore 9. I tried all the modifications but nothing worked.

So i changed the OS to Ubuntu 12.04 and the test worked perfectly.
By executing `` ./boftest `perl -e 'print "A" x 200'` `` , the `$eip` register value was overwritten to `0x41414141` where `0x41` is the hexadecimal value of 'A' caracter, which means that the buffer overflow test worked.

I think that the problem was with the Fedora OS, maybe it offered other levels of protection against buffer overflow that I wasn't aware of, while the ubuntu 12.04 version didn't. I only needed the command `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` for the test to work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible outcome is that the copy overwrites the stack of whatever was on the stack before main was invoked. You are checking the registers. Check the stack instead from where EPB points to.

EIP is the instruction pointerregister so I don't understand why you think that would change in some interesting way. Note that machine instructions are not on the stack in x86. Also there are no guarantee that the return address is on the stack so you won't necessarily modify it with an overflow write if that is what you want.

If you want to modify the EIP you need to modify some function pointer or something. Add a function pointer by buffer and then call it at the end of main and see if you modify EIP by overflowing writing over the function pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but my problem eventually was with the OS Fedora that offered extra-protection agaisnt buffer overflow that I wasn't aware of. I tried the test on Ubuntu and it worked. In fact, the goal was to modify the return adress of the program, which is stored in the stack. So when $eip will be pointing to the return address in the end, it will point to an overwritten value that we changed.